# Compute eigenvalues of a square matrix given LU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have heard from here, [Eigenvalues for LU decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259650/eigenvalues-for-lu-decomposition) , that the eigenvalues of A are NOT the same ones for U, given $A=LU$. However, if A is a symmetric matrix, is it possible to still use the LU decomposition to compute the eigenvalue, especially when it it known that $U=DL^T$?

There were some cases where I was able to get an LU decomposition of a symmetric matrix, test the diagonals of U for them being eigenvalues, only to find that they satisfy $|A-u_{kk}I| = 0$, but then the only solution for $(A-u_{kk}I)\overrightarrow x = \overrightarrow 0$ has $\overrightarrow x = \overrightarrow 0$ as the only solution! Is it then true that the fact that $c:|A-cI|=0$ doesn't necessarily make c and eigenvalue of A?

Answer (score 2):

The entries in $U$ have little or no relation to the eigenvalues of $A$ so it is not surprising that 
$$(A-u_{kk}I)\overrightarrow x = \overrightarrow 0 $$ 
gives $\overrightarrow x = \overrightarrow 0 $.

However $c:|A-cI|=0$ does give the eigenvalues.

Only thing you can claim is that $LU$ and $UL$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues. If $L$ and $U$ are both non-singular then $UL$ will usually (but not always) have a "better" eigenstructure. Beyond that, not much can be said even if $A$ is symmetric and $L^T = U$

Answer (score 2):

By the Sylvester theorem of inertia, the eigenvalues of A will have the same sign structure as the diagonal entries of $U$ resp. $D$.

More can not be said, as per user44197.

One can use the LU decomposition in a similar manner as the QR decomposition to make an GR algorithm

$L_kU_k=A_k$, $A_{k+1}=U_kL_k$

which will converge for the same reason the QR algorithm converges. However, this generalized GR algorithm will often be numerically very unstable.

Comment: ...this is why the LR algorithm often needs something like pivoting to stabilize it, which complicates the analysis of the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the LU decomposition of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ is a lower diagonal matrix $L \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ and an upper diagonal matrix $U \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times M}$ such that,
$$ A = LU $$

Without loss of generality we can assume that either $U$ or $L$ has a full diagonal of ones, by the uniqueness of the $LDU$ decomposition algorithm, and we know that,
$$ \det A = \det LU = (\det L) (\det U) $$

Suppose that $L$ has ones on the diagonal, then $\det A = \det U = \prod_{i=1}^M u_{ii}$. Which is what you might expect.

**The problem is that LU decomposition algorithms are not stable for every square matrix.** Instead people use algorithms which first permute the rows and columns of the input matrix, in order to ensure that it produces a stable result. For example, in [partial pivoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#LU_factorization_with_Partial_Pivoting), a permutation matrix $P$ is computed, with the property that,
$$ PA = LU $$

In this case, in order to compute the determinant of $A$, we must first compute the determinant of $P$. Fortunately, $ P = \prod_{i = 1}^K P_i$, where $P_i$ are single row permutations, and so $ \det(P) \in \{-1,1\} $. We have that, $ \det(P) = \prod_{i=1}^K \det(P_i) $, and so, $\det(P) = -1$ if $K$ is odd, and $|P| = 1$ if $K$ is even.

The problem now is finding $K$, which can easily be computed if you have access to the implementation. So far as I know, it is more difficult in third party libraries.